# How to edit a sealed secret in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, bitnami, kubernetes-secrets, sealedsecret

I've a kubernetes sealed secret with encrypted data in it. How can I edit the sealed secret like editing a deployment using command "kubectl edit deployment".

I know kubectl edit secret works on normal secrets not on sealed secrets.

```
apiVersion: bitnami.com/v1alpha1
kind: SealedSecret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: my-secret
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
  encryptedData:
    password: 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
    username: 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
  template:
    data: null
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: my-secret
      namespace: test-ns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the existing **SealedSecret** by using `--merge-into` option in SealedSecret service. You can simply copy & paste the encrypted data into a **json** and **merge** this to the existing **SealedSecret** like this

```
$ echo -n bar | kubectl create secret generic mysecret --dry-run=client --from-file=foo=/dev/stdin -o json \
  | kubeseal > mysealedsecret.json
$ echo -n baz | kubectl create secret generic mysecret --dry-run=client --from-file=bar=/dev/stdin -o json \
  | kubeseal --merge-into mysealedsecret.json
```

When the sealedsecret needs to decrypt and work the same as normal **secrets** in kubernetes then both sealedsecrets and secrets need to be in the same **namespace**.

For more detailed information refer this official [sealedsecrets github page](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets#update-existing-secrets)

To know more about the usage of SealedSecret refer to this [document](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets#usage)

Comment: Hi @P Nishanth Reddy have you got time to check this answer? is it useful?